# LetsEncrypt is not installing on Amazon ec2 Ubuntu tomcat. 'Challenge failed for domain example.com.'

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

I'm trying to install LetsEncrypt on my Tomcat server on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu with this code.

```
# certbot certonly --standalone -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

And it throws the error below.
I googled for this and the problem seems that it cannot make connection to server with the domain I put in. 
But weird thing is that I can connect to my server if I directly type the domain on browser. (with http)
The port 80, 22, 443, 8080 is open properly.
What am I missing?

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator standalone, Installer None
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for example.com
http-01 challenge for www.example.com
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain example.com
Challenge failed for domain www.example.com
http-01 challenge for example.com
http-01 challenge for www.example.com
Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: example.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/YmDEdGOXkYRjQxYCU25X8W8-69ETcVQ1gqeYchCIW5k
   [{myIpAddress}]: "<!doctype html><html lang=\"en\"><head><title>HTTP
   Status 404 – Not Found</title><style type=\"text/css\">body
   {font-family:Tahoma"

   Domain: www.example.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/yd_UiHnU4TpgPV1bt_MmQS24_nN8Gy3Ok6HeHwN9y10
   [{myIpAddress}]: "<!doctype html><html lang=\"en\"><head><title>HTTP
   Status 404 – Not Found</title><style type=\"text/css\">body
   {font-family:Tahoma"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

Comment: Does the file http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/YmDEdGOXkYRjQxYCU25X8W8-69ETcVQ1gqeYchCIW5k actually exist on your server?

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks for comment!. If I create this file manually with the name of previous try, can it be working? cause It seems like the filename changes every time.

Comment: The name changes everytime, yes. Can you check on your actual ec2 machine wether or not the files are there, ideally while certbot is running because I am not sure if it removed the files afterwards. If the files are there but you still get a 404 on the browser / by letsencrypt then this is a tomcat issue because e.g. the tomcat cannot access or does not allow access to the files.

Comment: @luk2302 is the .well-known folder supposed to be in /root dir? It doesn't seem to exist. When I run `ls -a` in /root directory, the result is `.   ..    .bash_history    .bashrc    .local    .profile    .ssh    snap`